# How do you get the current URL for a Python uwsgi app?

Tags: python, uwsgi

I'm using this uwsgi app:
http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki

```
def application(env, start_response):
  start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
  return "Hello World"
```

I'd like to know what my current URL is, for example:

localhost:9090/some/path/here?a=b&c=d

For some reason this isn't in the docs.  Am I missing something fundamental here?  What should I be looking up?  How do I get the current URL?

Also, how do you get stuff like:

Cookies, Accept Language, Headers, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all in `env`, and [`wsgiref.util`](http://docs.python.org/library/wsgiref.html#module-wsgiref.util) can help you get to it. And none of it is specific to uWSGI, which is just a WSGI container.

Answer (score 1):

Most (if not all) servers is based on Apache (grandaddy). The environment is standardized.

Try: `env['HTTP_HOST'], env['PATH_INFO'], env['HOST_NAME'], env['REQUEST_METHOD'], env['REQUEST_URI']`